# Does "anything go" against a Canaanite?

Tags: halacha, canaan

Tanach mentions how the Israelites were supposed to drive out the Canaanites but failed to.

If one lives in the time of Tanach:

Is one liable for murdering, robbing, coveting from, burning down the field of, etc. a Canaanite who retains his religion and is thus not a Ger Toshav?

My enlightenment-tainted morality would say that you can't, but it could very well be that the Canaanite is liable to be conquered.

Comment: Why would you think it isn't permitted to remove him from the land? And why would you think it would be permitted to torment him just for funsies?

Comment: For that matter, we have to offer peace before attempting war (Geirei Toshav are not included), we have to allow an escape route when laying siege.... Even within war it's not "anything goes".

Comment: "the Canaanite is chayiv to be conquered"? What should he do, hire a hit man on himself?

Answer (score -3):

To harm a Canaanite because of his religion absolves the whole history of antisemitism, for the Christians could also claim their religion is correct and since Jews are not saved by Jesus, they can murder, rob, covert, burn, etc. a Jew who retains his religion of Judaism and is thus not saved. That is the very sin of the Christians! The answer is no. Maimonides writes that we do not harm anyone unless they harm us first or if they reject a peace offer as in a time of war.

Please follow your enlightenment-tainted morality and don't fly into buildings because Allah says to kill the idolators. No offense.